# Компоненты с небольшими отличиями в логике и представлении

Tags: reactjs

Только начинают в Реакт. Есть компонент Paragraph, который представляет собой заголовок и текст под ним:

```
<div className="paragraph">
  <h3 className="paragraph__title">Заголовок</h3>
  <p className="paragraph__text">Текст</p>
</div>
```

Данный компонент может немного модифицироваться в моем приложении. Так, текст может быть заменен ссылками на пдф, где каждая ссылка, логично - кликабельна, а перед ссылкой имеется иконка:

```
<div className="paragraph">
  <h3 className="paragraph__title">Заголовок</h3>
  <a href="" className="paragraph__link">
    <div className="paragraf__icon-container">
      <Icon icon="clarity"/>
    </div>
    Специальное предложение. Презентация.pdf
  </a>
</div>
```

Так же данный компонент может представлять собой список контактов. Т.е. Остается заголовок, и ниже  появлются две строки - первая - обычный текст, перед которым стоит иконка - это ФИО человека. Вторая и третья строка - это ссылки на телефон и почту и вначале каждой этой строки стоит своя иконка:

```
<div className="paragraph">
  <h3 className="paragraph__title">Контакты</h3>
  <div className="paragraf__item">
    <div className="paragraf__icon-container">
      <Icon icon="person" />
    </div>
    Вита Гульгхамовна Золотозуб
  </div>
  <a href="" className="paragraph__link">
    <div className="paragraf__icon-container">
      <Icon icon="telephone" />
    </div>
    8 (123) 456 78 89
  </a>
  <a href="" className="paragraph__link">
    <div className="paragraf__icon-container">
      <Icon icon="mail"/>
    </div>
    example@examle.ru
  </a>
</div>
```

Каким образом выдержать нормальную композицию компонентов. Из того, что "почерпнул" в интернетах:

1. Создать два компонент, рассчитанных на разные пропсы и отличающуюся логику. Например, создать компонент `<ParagraphItem />` и `<ParagraphLink />` В `<ParagraphItem />` зашить логику, что если приходит ссылка на иконку в пропсах - то рендерится `.paragraf__item`, если в пропсах только текст, то `.paragraph__text`. Так же и с `<ParagraphLink />` - есть ссылка на пдф, почту или телефон. Разные пропсы - разный рендеринг.
2. Создать один компонент `<ParagraphItem />` но логику его работы зациклить на пропсы - разные пропсы - совершенно разный рендеринг и логика (где-то есть клик по ссылке, где-то только текст и.т.д.)
   Обо подхода мне кажутся несколько ущербными. В первом необходимо деление на множество довольно маленьких компонентов, которые в дальнейшем все равно в каждом прописывается своя логика через распознавание пропсов и возврат разных элементов в зависимости от них. Во втором - сложность одного компонента. Да он один, но внутри него черти что. В итоге вопрос знатокам - если есть компоненты, логика и представление которых незначительно отличаются - как поступать в этом случае?

Comment: не вижу никаких проблем в 1 способе. Чем вам не нравится деление на множество компонентов?

Comment: Смущает следующее: у меня есть три варианта компонента:
1. Просто текст:
--Заголовок
--Текст
--Текст
2. Просто ссылки:
--Заголовок
--Ссылка
--Ссылка
3. Текст и ссылки:
--Заголовок
--Текст
--Ссылка
По идее я могу сделать три компонента <ParagraphText /> <ParagraphLink /> <ParagraphContact /> НО у этих компонентов есть кое-что общее. Например в стилях. Получается, мне надо будет дублировать стили, если по БЭМ

Answer (score 2):

#### Концепция React - декомпозиция

> В идеале, каждый компонент должен реализовывать свою логику и не зависеть от других, а так же не зависеть от контекста. Желательно создавать атомарные компоненты, которые можно переиспользовать по всему коду проекта.

В вашем примере, необходимо выделить компоненты, которые отвечают за ту или иную логику. 
Давай те разберем ваш код и посмотрим, что можно декомпозировать:

- Заголовок
- Отображение иконки
- Отображение текста в параграфе
- Отображение блока с именем
- Отображение ссылки с телефоном или email

**Декомпозируем**

Создаем компонент вывода заголовка:

```
const ParagraphTitle = ({text}) => <h3 className="paragraph__title">{text}</h3>
```

Создаем компонент вывода обычного текста(параграфа):

```
const ParagraphBlock = ({text}) => <p className="paragraph__text">{text}</p>
```

Создаем компонент вывода изображения:

```
const ParagraphIcon = ({ iconName }) => 
    <div className="paragraf__icon-container">
      <Icon icon={iconName} />
    </div>
```

Начинаем комбинировать наши компоненты:

```
const ParagraphItem = ({name, icon}) => {
  return (
    <div className="paragraf__item">
      <ParagraphIcon iconName={icon} />
      {name}
    </div>
  )
}

const ParagraphLink = ({item, icon}) => {
  return (
    <a href="#" className="paragraph__link">
      <ParagraphIcon iconName={icon} />
      {item}
    </a>
  )
}
```

Осталось самое сложное в выборе исполнения - определить компонент, который **будет реализовывать логику**, когда и какой компонент отображать.

Т.к. в ваших примерах заголовок есть всегда, то я, например, решил определять вывод по полученным пропсам(предположив, что в пропсах будет только одна комбинация).

```
const Paragraph = ({title, text, phone, name, email, icon}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ParagraphTitle text={title} />
      {text && <ParagraphBlock text={text} />}
      {name && <ParagraphItem name={name} icon={icon} />}
      {(phone || email) ? <ParagraphLink item={phone || email} icon={icon}/> : null}
    </>
  )
}
```

Полный вариант реализации декомпозиции кода ниже с примером

```js
const data = [{
  title: 'Именной текст',
  name: 'Черззаборногузадерищенко',
  icon: 'hand'
}, {
  title: 'Простой текст',
  text: 'Это статья о декомпозиции элементов'
}, {
  title: 'Выводим телефон',
  phone: '1 234 567-89-00',
  icon: 'lags'
}, {
  title: 'Выводим email',
  email: 'myanswer@react.org',
  icon: 'mail'
}]

const Icon = (img) => {
  return (
<img src={img} />
  )
}

const Paragraph = ({title, text, phone, name, email, icon}) => {
  return (
<>
  <ParagraphTitle text={title} />
  {text && <ParagraphBlock text={text} />}
  {name && <ParagraphItem name={name} icon={icon} />}
  {(phone || email) ? <ParagraphLink item={phone || email} icon={icon}/> : null}
</>
  )
}

const ParagraphBlock = ({text}) => {
  return (
<p className="paragraph__text">{text}</p>
  )
}

const ParagraphTitle = ({text}) => {
  return (
<h3 className="paragraph__title">{text}</h3>
  )
}

const ParagraphIcon = ({ iconName }) => {
  return (
<div className="paragraf__icon-container">
  <Icon icon={iconName} />
</div>
  )
}

const ParagraphItem = ({name, icon}) => {
  return (
<div className="paragraf__item">
  <ParagraphIcon iconName={icon} />
  {name}
</div>
  )
}

const ParagraphLink = ({item, icon}) => {
  return (
<a href="#" className="paragraph__link">
  <ParagraphIcon iconName={icon} />
  {item}
</a>
  )
}

export default function App() {  
  return (
<div className="App">
  <Paragraph title={'Смотрим'} />
  {data.map(item => {
    return <Paragraph { ...item } />
  })
  }
</div>
  );
}
```

[Рабочий пример декомпозиции в React, можно поиграться с реализацией](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-grass-e5kes0?file=/src/App.js)

Таким образом мы **реализовали независимые компоненты**, которые будут отображать нужные нам данные без дублирования кода и логики. 
Когда прибежит очередной *безумный заказчик* с вот такими глазами **О_О** и воплями: *Хочу поменять стиль у всех иконок!*, вам не нужно будет ковырять весь код и выискивать, где вы используете компонент. 
Достаточно будет в одном месте, в самом компоненте, изменить вывод отображения иконки. Заказчику обозначаем 3 дня, тыкая по макету 100500 выводов иконок, сами за 1 час меняем стили и приходим к заказчику - мол постарались, сделали за 1 день! Все довольны, все молодцы, мы герои, идем дальше!

Comment: пора заводить золотые страницы на SO

Comment: @DaniilLoban что за страницы такие? Первый раз слышу. В голове понимаю, о чем речь, а вот на практике...

Comment: ну типа самые лучшие ответы и т.п.