# React. Как передать сигнал в дочерний компонент?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hook

Изучаю React и столкнулся с проблемой.

Мне нужно дать дочернему компоненту (Button) "сигнал" о том что нужно изменить стейт active на false, но не могу никак передать. Если передаю через prop просто false, то не меняет так как useEffect не вызывается потому что состояние не менялось. Понимаю что что-то делаю не так, пытался исправить разными способами, но решение так и не нашел. Буду благодарен за помощь.

FastFilter.jsx

```
export const FastFilter = () => {
    const [selectedIncludes, setSelectedIncludes] = useState([])
    const [activeStatus, setActiveStatus] = useState(false)

    const poolReapeters = (data) => {

    }

    const onButtonActived = (data, state) => {
        const recived = Array.isArray(data.children) ? { children: data.children[1].replace(/\s/g, ''), type: data.type } : data
        if (state) {
            setSelectedIncludes([...selectedIncludes, recived])
        } else {
            setSelectedIncludes([...selectedIncludes.filter(function (name) {
                return name.children !== recived.children
            })])
        }

    }

    const resetCat = () => {
        setActiveStatus(false)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        poolReapeters(selectedIncludes)
        console.log(selectedIncludes)
    }, [selectedIncludes])

    return (
        <>
            <Title>Швидкий пошук за фiльтрами</Title>
            <Reapeter>
                <Button type={"model"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}><SiBmw /> BMW</Button>
                <Button type={"model"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}><SiMercedes /> Mercedes</Button>
                <Button type={"model"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}><SiAudi /> Audi</Button>
                <Button type={"model"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}><SiVolkswagen /> Volkswagen</Button>
                <Button type={"model"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}><SiOpel /> Opel</Button>
            </Reapeter>
            <Reapeter>
                <Button type={"color"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Сiра</Button>
                <Button type={"color"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Бiла</Button>
                <Button type={"color"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Чорна</Button>
                <Button type={"color"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Червона</Button>
                <Button type={"color"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Синя</Button>
                <Button type={"color"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Зелена</Button>
                <Button type={"color"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Жовта</Button>
                <Button type={"color"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Коричнева</Button>
            </Reapeter>
            <Reapeter>
                <Button type={"year"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>1990-2000</Button>
                <Button type={"year"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>2000-2005</Button>
                <Button type={"year"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>2005-2010</Button>
                <Button type={"year"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>2010-2013</Button>
                <Button type={"year"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>2013-2017</Button>
                <Button type={"year"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>2017-2020</Button>
                <Button type={"year"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>2020-2023</Button>
            </Reapeter>
            <Reapeter>
                <Button type={"state"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Ідеальний стан</Button>
                <Button type={"state"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Сліди використання</Button>
                <Button type={"state"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Після ДТП</Button>
                <Button type={"state"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>На запчастини</Button>
            </Reapeter>
            <Reapeter>
                <Button type={"capacity"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>1.6 л</Button>
                <Button type={"capacity"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>1.8 л</Button>
                <Button type={"capacity"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>1.9 л</Button>
                <Button type={"capacity"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>2.0 л</Button>
                <Button type={"capacity"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>2.2 л</Button>
                <Button type={"capacity"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>2.4 л</Button>
                <Button type={"capacity"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>2.6 л</Button>
                <Button type={"capacity"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>2.8 л</Button>
            </Reapeter>
            <Reapeter>
                <Button type={"carType"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Універсал</Button>
                <Button type={"carType"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Седан</Button>
                <Button type={"carType"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Хетчбек</Button>
                <Button type={"carType"} onActive={onButtonActived} activeStatus={activeStatus}>Купе</Button>
            </Reapeter>
            <ButtonApplySearchContainer><ButtonApplySearchSubContainer><ButtonApplySearch>Показати {`(${20})`}</ButtonApplySearch><ButtonApplyReload onClick={resetCat}><IoMdRefresh /></ButtonApplyReload></ButtonApplySearchSubContainer></ButtonApplySearchContainer>
        </>
    )
}
```

Button.jsx

```
export const Button = ({ children, onActive, type, activeStatus }) => {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
    const onSelected = () => {
        setActive(active => !active)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        onActive({ children, type }, active)
    }, [active])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(activeStatus)
        if (active) {
            setActive(activeStatus)
        }
    }, [activeStatus])



    return (
        <ButtonStyled isActive={active} onClick={onSelected}>{children}</ButtonStyled>
    )
}
```

Comment: А это нормально, что у вас статус один на все кнопки?

Comment: Хм, ну я так сделал так как если делать стейт под каждую кнопку это займет очень много строк и сомневаюсь что так будет правильно

Comment: Посмотрите [компоненты с собственным состоянием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474996/1475029#1475029) или [компоненты с состояние в родителе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1489288/1489301#1489301)

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас посмотрю, спасибо. Ещё хотел добавить что в компоненте Button у меня есть стейт Active и он как раз отвечает за статус кнопки (активная\не активная), и мне нужно при нажатии кнопки из вне (кнопка сброс), устанавливать этот стейт в false на всех Button. Если говорить в целом, это некие тэги и я хочу реализовать кнопку сброса.

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку, вы предаете данные в родительский компонет, однако функуция `onButtonActived`  меняет только `selectedIncludes` которая нигде не используется(нет в рендере, нет перерисовки)

Comment: И вот это посмотрите, может поможет вам изменить взгляд в нужном русле. [Декомпозиция реакт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463823/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/1464004#1464004)

Comment: Спасибо большое, стало более яснее, пойду посмотрю материалы