# Как внутри REACT компонента сделать цикл, если используется useState?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, checkbox, react-hook, state

Изначально отправляю массив объектов чтобы вывести список чекбоксов.

```
<Checkbox checkboxProps = {checkboxButtonsDataArr}/>
```

Нужно чтобы на выходе внутри `<form></form>` было 3 `<label></label>`

Массив с пропсами:

```
[
    {id: 1, title: 'Тест 1', name: 'name1', checked: false},
    {id: 2, title: 'Тест 2', name: 'name2', checked: false},
    {id: 3, title: 'Тест 3', name: 'name3', checked: true}
]
```

Компонент:

```
interface IChecked {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    name: string;
    checked: boolean;
}

interface ICheckedArr {
    checkboxProps: IChecked[];
}

const Checkbox = ({ checkboxProps }: ICheckedArr) => {
  console.log(checkboxProps);

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        {checkboxProps.map((item) => {
          return (
            <label key={item.id}>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name={item.name}
                checked={checked}
                onChange={(e) => setChecked(e.target.checked)}
              />
              <span>{item.title}</span>
            </label>
          );
        })}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Checkbox;
```

Я пытался сделать общий useState, но создать useState для проверки на checked внутри цикла нельзя.

upd. Добавил мою попытку, но опять таки это ссылается на один и тот же setChecked и по клику они все checked

upd2. это не дубликат, в предложенном варианте нет setState в цикле

Comment: Извините Вы в документацию смотрели? Там тема вывода нескольких компонент рассмотренна довольно хорошо (использование `map`  в рендере). Откуда беруться такие вопросы... Или поясните если я чего не понял, через редактирование вопроса, дополнив его подробностями.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отрисовать список(массив) в ReactJS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453065/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-reactjs)

Comment: @DaniilLoban изменил, не хотел нагружать лишними подробностями, т.к думал что, то что я пробовал вообще не правильно..

Comment: Так получше, всегда лучше не жалеть с подробностями. Только не понятно что именно не получается, т.е. : какое действие, какой ожидаемый результат, и результат сейчас. Можно простыми словами даже, суть задачи.

Comment: [Это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1491364/) или [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478184/) или [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474996/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc/1475029#1475029)

Comment: Ваша основная ошибка, что checked у вас на весь компонет, а нужен для каждого свой

Comment: да, я знаю что он один на весь компонент. Суть вопроса в том, как динамически создавать useState? Он может 1 или 10, а в map по правилам нельзя создавать useState.

Comment: Вам не нужно плодить стейты. Вынесете каждый элемент в свой компонент или положить массив в стейт и меняйте данные там. По ссылкам выше есть все примеры

Comment: У меня чекбокс-лист из 3 пунктов(их может быть и больше). Как я думал, правильнее один раз передать массив с данными. Чем делать чекбокс-комонтент на 1 чекбокс, а затем на чекбокс-лист. Или так вернее?

в ролике Ulbi TV (от А до Я), он создавал отдельный общий useState в который записывались объекты ново-созданных объектов, а у меня просто приходящий массив. Я пытался как он, но не получилось.

Comment: Т.е. задача в том чтобы из массива сделать чекбоксы и хранить их состояние в useState? тогда могу предложить вариант — делается компонент для 1 чекбокса, там же стейт весь разносится на несколько  (id, title, name, checked) там же обрабатывается, это не будет приводить к перерисовке каждого чекбокса в списке, если нужен код могу показать.

Comment: Меньше смотрите видео, больше практикуйтесь и экспериментируйте. [Декомпозиция - концепция реакт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463823/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/1464004#1464004) - почитайте еще это, как разделить логику

Comment: похоже так и придется. Помощь не нужна спасибо, я так уже делал) Просто думал сделать один чекбокс-лист компонент правильнее, удобнее и кода меньше чем несколько маленьких.

Comment: упс... опубликовал, правда пока занят так что может где косяк.

Comment: да, примерно, думал о том же, это мне определенно будет полезно. Спасибо!

Comment: @NaN-Simon дополнил чтобы не перерендеривало список.

Comment: Очень исчерпывающе, огромное спасибо!

Comment: если у тебя уже есть `checked` в том, что ты передаешь, зачем тебе еще и useState заводить?

Comment: @Grundy чтобы чекбокс работал. Если не подключить useState он же не будет меняться checked/unchecked

Comment: @NaN-Simon, здесь нет никакой связи с `useState`.

Comment: @NaN-Simon перенес в песочницу https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-joji-sxw5d7?file=/src/components/chekboxList/CheckboxList.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить вариант — делается компонент `Checkbox` для одного элемента, там же стейт для `checked`, таким образом каждый чекбокс хранит свое состояние. Изменение этого состояния не будет приводить к перерисовке всего списка. Но пользы в этом мало если мы не можем получить все данные в одном месте, именно в списке чекбоксов `CheckboxList` мы и будем хранить данные. Для передачи состояния от компонента `Checkbox` в данные `CheckboxList` используется функция `update` — так как она обновляет вложенные данные стейта, перерисовка списка происходить не будет.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script type="text/babel">
      window.useState = React.useState;
      window.useEffect = React.useEffect
      
      const data = [
        {id: 1, title: 'Тест 1', name: 'name1', checked: false},
        {id: 2, title: 'Тест 2', name: 'name2', checked: false},
        {id: 3, title: 'Тест 3', name: 'name3', checked: true}
      ]

      const Checkbox = ({ id, title, name, checked:ch, update={update} }) => {
        const [checked, setChecked] = useState(ch);
        const onChange = (e) => {
          setChecked(e.target.checked)
          update(id, e.target.checked)
        }
        return (
          <div>
            <label key={id}>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name={name}
                checked={checked}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
              <span>{title}</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        );
      };

      const CheckboxList = ({data:dt}) => {
        const [data, setData] = useState(dt);
        
        const update = (id, checked) => {
          data.find(e => e.id === id).checked = checked
          console.log(data.map(e => e.checked).toString())
        }

        return (
          <div>
            <form>
              {data.map(({id, title, name, checked}) => {
                return (
                  <Checkbox 
                    key={id}
                    id={id}
                    type="checkbox"
                    title={title}
                    name={name}
                    checked={checked}
                    update={update}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      };

      const App = () => {
        return (
          <div>
            <CheckboxList data={data}/>
          </div>
        );
      };

      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: менять стейт простым присваиванием `data.find(e => e.id === id).checked = checked` плохая идея

Comment: @Grundy я так понимаю через useState будет вернее? Используя setData в этом примере. Я пытался, не подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка? с 

TS2345: Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<IChecked[]>'.

setData(data.find(e=>e.id === id)!.checked = checked)

Возможно, не совсем верно, спрашивать о TS ошибке на этом примере.. могу дать ссылку, если будет понятнее

Comment: @NaN-Simon, `setData` ожидает новый массив. А ты пытаешься передать вместо этого `boolean`.

Comment: я изменил метод update вот так:     
data.find(e=>e.id === id)!.checked = checked
console.log(data);
setData(data).
В консоли он меняется, но реакт не перендеривает, из-за чего это может быть? 
По факту, конечно не сильно изменил, просто не пойму почему не происходит перерендер/

Comment: @NaN-Simon вернул код чтобы было с `useState`

Comment: @Grundy Подскажите плз, это все еще плохой способ? Просто в моем примере это хотя бы заработало.

const [data, setData] = useState(dataProps);

const newArr = data.slice();

const update = (id, checked) => {

  newArr.find(e=>e.id === id).checked = checked;

  setData(newArr)

}

Comment: @NaN-Simon это особенность реакта если меняются вложенные данные — он этого не видит, только на корневые реагирует (массив —  ссылочный тип, если осталась та же ссылка реакции не будет,нужен новый массив)

Comment: @NaN-Simon я бы не назвал это прямо уж плохим способом, просто в реакте запрещено менять данные useState без вызвова setState, одним словом такие вещи может быть сложно потом дебажить, конкретно такие правки данных никто обычно не применяет.

Comment: @DaniilLoban я так и понял), просто не понял почему у вас получилось, хотя... я сделал чуть-чуть по другому. Пока вы тут хотел пару вопросов задать)  "const CheckboxList = ({data:dt})" :dt это передача массива? И пропс  update={update} в Checkbox тоже не совсем ясен, как он сам себя передает?

Comment: `({data:dt})` - обозначает что мы из переданного props извлекем `data` и назовем его `dt` ,  `update={update}` обозначает что мы передаем компоненту пропс `update`  в котором передаем функцию `update`

Comment: С update не совсем понятно, но разберусь со временем(просто TS ругался Parameter 'update' cannot reference itself.ts(2372)), Спасибо)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143230/discussion-between-daniil-loban-and-nan-simon).